# Find the following limit:

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

I struggle with computing the limit of a given expression but can't get any progress. I give here the step where I am blocked.

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
   \frac{1}{4\pi \sqrt{n} \log(n)}
   \left[ \frac{\sin\left(2 \pi s_n \frac{\log{(n)}}{\sqrt n}\right)}
               {\sin\left(\frac{s_n\pi}{n}\right)}
         +\cos\left(\frac{2\pi s_{n} \log(n)}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \right]$$

where $s_n \in \{1,\dots,n\}$. (This means that $s_{n}$ here can take any value in this set, but the set depend on $n$ also. So, since I take the limit as $n\to \infty$, I can say that $s_{n} \in \{1, 2, \dots \}$.)

All suggestions for the computation of this limit are welcomed.

Comment: The limit depends on knowing the values of all the $s_n$'s If $s_n=1$ for all $n$, the limit will be very different than if $s_n=n$ for example.

Comment: Yes, since $\dfrac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$, if $s_n$ is constant you get one behavior, if $s_n$ is linear in $n$, it is very different...

Comment: If $s_{n}$ is constant, the limit is zero. But I think the interesting case is to consider that $s_{n}$ is linear in $n$.